# google drive deletes files locally that's deleted on cloud

Tags: storage, cloud

That creates a single point of failure: if my account is hacked, and my recycle bin is not big enough, all my data would be gone. Terrifying.

Am I right?

There's no place to change this setting, right?

Comment: That’s how nearly all cloud services work. It’s certainly how Google Drive works.  Cloud services are not typically considered to be a good solution if it’s the only backup. You can mitigate your concerns with the use of multiple cloud services, at the expense of duplication of data, to multiple locations on the drive.

Comment: This ^^^ Mega and Yandex Disk have their own "recycle bin" that unless when explicitly emptied will keep all deleted files for some time (typically 30 days) but that is at the expense of user's quota, of course.

Comment: Even OneDrive has its own recycle bin that stores the "files you delete here are deleted everywhere" files for, like, 45 days.